# JQuery .click function not working in rails (with many possibly unrelated errors)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a fairly simple set of badges that, when clicked, should change the value of a hidden field and change color.

The html/erb is like this:

```
<div class="md-form mb-4 justify-contents-center">
  <label>Urgency</label>
  <span class="clickable badge badge-pill badge-urgency badge-high inactive" id="urgency-high">High</span>
  <span class="clickable badge badge-pill badge-urgency badge-medium inactive" id="urgency-medium">Medium</span>
  <span class="clickable badge badge-pill badge-urgency badge-low inactive" id="urgency-low">Low</span>
  <span class="clickable badge badge-pill badge-urgency badge-nonurgent inactive" id="urgency-nonurgent">Non-Urgent</span>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :urgency, id: "urgency-field" %>
</div>
```

And my JQuery reads like this:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("THINGS");
    $('#badge-high').click(function(){
      console.log("HIGH THINGS");
      $('.badge-urgency').addClass('inactive');
      $('#badge-high').removeClass('inactive');
      $('#urgency-field').val("High");
    });
    $('#badge-medium').click(function(){
      $('.badge-urgency').addClass('inactive');
      $('#badge-medium').removeClass('inactive');
      $('#urgency-field').val("Medium");
    });
    $('#badge-low').click(function(){
      $('.badge-urgency').addClass('inactive');
      $('#badge-low').removeClass('inactive');
      $('#urgency-field').val("Low");
    });
    $('#badge-nonurgent').click(function(){
      $('.badge-urgency').addClass('inactive');
      $('#badge-nonurgent').removeClass('inactive');
      $('#urgency-field').val("Non-Urgent");
    });
    $('.mdb-select').materialSelect();
  });
</script>
```

The console is showing "THINGS", so I know it's reaching inside the JQuery, but "HIGH THINGS" never happens, even when `#badge-high`is clicked.

I get the following console errors, but if I remove the JQuery from the page altogether they still show up, so I'm pretty sure they're unrelated.

[image]

Any ideas as to what could be broken?

Comment: @muistooshort Argh.  Yes.  Moronic issues abound.  Thank you!  I'll happily choose your answer if you want to write it up.

Answer (score 0):

It seems likely that this is caused by other scripts you have included in your code. Have you tried checking the order in which you have included other scripts in your HTML?

Sometimes certain scripts need to be included before others for correct functioning.